# question about if condition in binary search

Tags: arrays, algorithm, c++11, binary-search

```
int binary_search(const vector<int>& matrix, int target) {

        int start = 0, end = matrix.size() - 1; 
        while (start < end) {
            int mid = start + (end - start)/2;
            if (matrix[mid] <= target) {  // if (matrix[mid] < target)
                start = mid + 1;
            } else {
                end = mid;
            }
        }
        return end;
}
int main()
{
    cout << binary_search({1, 3, 7, 10, 20}, 15);
    return 0;
}
```

Hi, I am confusing what's the difference between "<=" and "<=" in while loop.

The most confusing part of binary search is I am never sure which one to use "<=" or "<" whenever it comes to the condition statement: while loop condition or if condition.

Even if I have a basic idea but when it comes to coding, how can I be confident and sure this should be "<=", that one should be "<".

I appreciate if someone can input.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually,

(1) when matrix[mid] == target you can directly return there itself.

(2) If start == end then you are looking at only one element ( whether it equals to target or not).

If it is not equal to the target then we say element not found else element found at a particular index

From your code, it seems that you have assumed the target will be present in the matrix and there you are directly returning "end" without start <= end which also works fine.

So if you don't assume that the target will be in the matrix then you must put the condition start <= end also.

Comment: Do not need  matrix[mid] == target because if so, start==end and matrix[start]==target after breaking the loop if there exists target in the array. <= or < makes difference when target is not in the array.

Comment: Yeah <= or < makes difference when the target is not in the array.